# Как прослушивать клик на TextView

Tags: java, android

Всем привет.
Пишу вторую программу и в процессе компиляции ошибка и есть неиспользуемый серый `import android.widget.EditText` далее по тексту и эмулятор показывает что программа не исполнена:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>       * What went wrong:
>       Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

я только в начале обучения, извините если вопрос примитивный.
В чем может быть причина? Заранее спасибо!

```
package com.example.user.MainActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mHelloTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mHelloTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    mHelloTextView.setText("Hello Kitty!");
}
```

}

источник кода брал здесь http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/android2.php

Comment: Не всегда Ctr+C и Ctr+V работает

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема в том что, вы не указали какой объект должен обработать событие onClick!

Вот пример на то что, вы хотите сделать

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Стартовый текст" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setText("Новый текст");
            }
        });
    }
```

Есть несколько способов обработки нажатия кнопки, я лишь показал один из них

Comment: я вам очень благодарен!

Comment: а где можно почитать о том как пишется подобный код?

Comment: На сегодняшний день очень много ресурсов, например startandroid.ru, в Ютюбе можете посмотреть